# Doctrine2 - Which method would be more appropriate?

Tags: mysql, sql, mongodb, doctrine-orm, database

Required data is kept in mysql. But, nullable data is kept in mongodb. Also, MongoDB will read data quickly. In this way the load is distributed. So, I'm using two database.

**The first way;**

**Mysql** database schema;

Settings.php;

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="settings")
 */
class Settings
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $userid;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="settings")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="userid", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $user;
```

and

**Mongodb** database schema;

```
/**
 * @MongoDB\Document(collection="settingsData")
 */
class SettingsData
{
    /**
     * @MongoDB\Id
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\Field(type="int")
     */
    protected $settingsid;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\Field(type="hash")
     */
    protected $data;

}
```

Through this method, I can set up a relational database. However, I need to open an extra table (mysql -> setting table). And I'm using Doctrine2 event listener for Entity-Document relationship.

**The second way;**

```
/**
 * @MongoDB\Document(collection="settings")
 */
class Settings
{
    /**
     * @MongoDB\Id
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\Field(type="int")
     */
    protected $userid;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\Field(type="hash")
     */
    protected $data;
}
```

In this method, I can add the data directly. No need for an extra table to retrieve data. I just need to write extra code. But the relationship broke down. Code will be difficult to follow. (And I've used the first method in most of the system. But they were only MySQL.)

The question; Which method would be more performance and **appropriate**?

Comment: cant you use [mongodb ODM from doctrine](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/) for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using both Doctrine ORM and MongoDB ODM, you can utilize [this extension](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/references.md) to map references between MySQL entities and MongoDB documents. It would obviously not provide any sort of referential integrity, but it would allow you to very easily navigate the relationship through getter methods and Proxy objects in your application (e.g. no need to collect an integer ID and issue a SQL query).

Based on your schema, it looks like you're only utilize MongoDB for a `$data` property, which is mapped as a hash type (MongoDB object). You're not actually defining a schema for this property with an embedded document, so I assume that you're not actually querying on this field and it's just storing arbitrary key/value data. If that's the case, would it not just be simpler to store the key/value data as a serialized or JSON string? Doctrine ORM even has a `json_array` [type mapping](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html) for that purpose.